Mount binds not working in Docker Compose
I am new to this and wanted to practice. I created a simple project:

Where I have a node frontend:

I setup express and nodemon. When I run my project locally it works, if I change the code and reload it reflects.
Dockerfile:
FROM node:18.12.1-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY ./src ./src

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]


package.json:
 "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon --watch \"./**\" --ext \"js\" --exec \"node src/index.js\""
  },

If I run docker run -v ./src:/src/app/ -p 8080:8080 davihlav/frontend:v1 while in frontend folder changing the code doesn't update.
Likewise in docker-compose.yml:
version: '3'
services:
  frontend:
    image: davihlav/frontend:v1
    build: ./frontend
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./frontend/src:/app/src

Running docker-compose up --build in the root folder code update doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

What's the point of copying src in your Dockerfile if you're just going to mount a volume over it?

See https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1802 and https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar/issues/1051

You need to invoke nodemon with --legacy-watch (as mentioned in the duplicate) to use nodemon's file watching feature in Docker.

@Wyck "dev": "nodemon --legacy-watch \"./**\" --ext \"js\" --exec \"node src/index.js\"" and it still does not work..

If you add the critical information to your question about why running nodemon with the fixes in the duplicate do not solve your problem, then you can petition to have your question reopened.  As of now, the code in your question doesn't even indicate that you are using the legacy watch.  You have some updating to do.  Do you believe that the duplicate is applicable to your situation or not?...and why?
